# 3D vector diagram in python - arrow heads not showing properly

Tags: python, vector, matplotlib, 3d

This is the plot I get from the code below:

```
    aa = np.zeros(len(self.depthrange))
    bb = np.zeros(len(self.depthrange))

    for i in range(0, self.n):
        goodin = ~np.isnan(self.u[:, i])
        bb[i] = self.u[goodin, i].mean()
        aa[i] = self.v[goodin, i].mean()

    speed = np.sqrt(bb**2 + aa**2)
    dirt = np.arctan2(bb, aa) * 180 / np.pi
    dirt[dirt < 360] += 360
    dirt[dirt > 360] -= 360
    binrange = -np.mean(self.variables.depth) + self.binrange[1, :]
    aa = speed * np.cos(dirt * np.pi / 180)
    bb = speed * np.sin(dirt * np.pi / 180)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.quiver(0, 0, binrange, aa, bb, np.zeros(len(bb)), pivot='tail', arrow_length_ratio=0.3, length=0.15, color='tomato', lw='2')
    ax.text(0, -0.025, -15, 'W', color='k', fontsize=15)
    ax.text(-0.025, 0, -15, 'S', color='k', fontsize=15)
    ax.text(0.025, 0, -15, 'N', color='k', fontsize=15)
    ax.text(0, 0.025, -15, 'E', color='k', fontsize=15)
    ax.set_zlim(-15, 0)
    ax.set_xlim(-0.25, 0.25)
    ax.set_ylim(-0.25, 0.25)
    plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
    #plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    ax.view_init(elev=18, azim=30)
    ax.dist = 8
    ax.set_xlabel('m/s')
    ax.set_ylabel('m/s')
    ax.set_zlabel('Depth (m)')
    ax.set_title('Mean Current Vector')
    ax.plot([0, 0], [0, 0], zs=[-15, 0], lw=2, color='grey')
    for i in range(0, self.n):
        ax.plot([-0.1*0.25, 0.1*0.25], [0, 0], zs=[binrange[i], binrange[i]], lw=2, color='grey')
        ax.plot([0, 0], [-0.1*0.25, 0.1*0.25], zs=[binrange[i], binrange[i]], lw=2, color='grey')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

There are arrow heads present as you can see a difference in the colour of the line however they do not look like arrows, does anyone know how I get the arrows to show properly?

Many thanks,

Comment: Show the rest of the code that generates the data you use in that function. It's difficult to reproduce it from an image. Besides I don't see any instruction in the line of code you've shown that says the arrow heads are grey or that the text with cardinal points should appear. My guess is you are doing a mistake which is not necessarily in the part of the code you've shared.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow heads (in red) are there. I believe this to be a bug in the matplotlib library, but in any case the problem is with the components (U,V,W). Try to rotate them slightly in the axis of the shaft and you should see the heads appear. Here is a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = (0, 0, 0)
Y = (0, 1, 2)
Z = (0,0,0)
ax.quiver(X,Y,Z,(0,2,1),(1,1,1),(1,3,1),length=0.05,arrow_length_ratio=0.3)
plt.show()
```

, the result is this:

[image: Arrow heads in Axes 3D]

Notice how one the arrows suffers from the same problem as yours. The others are fine. The only difference between them is the components.

I think you should try providing the data (you're using a class that we can't see so your plot remains with difficult reproduction) along with the code, in case you'll have problems in setting up the correct components.